# MVC RottenPotatoes application

Tags: model-view-controller

Here are my notes about the MVC:

> - An application organized according to the architectural pattern called Model-View-Controller (MVC) consists of three main types of code:
>
>   1. **Models** are concerned with the data manipulated by the application: how to store it, how to operate on it, and how to change it.
>
>      - An MVC app typically has a model for each type of entity manipulated by the app.
>      - Because models deal with the application's data, they contain the code that communicates with the storage tier.
>   2. **Views** are presented to the user and contain information about the models with which users can interact.
>
>      - The views serve as the interface between the system's users and its data; for example, in Rotten Potatoes you can list movies and add new movies by clicking on links or buttons in the views.
>   3. **Controllers** mediate the interaction in both directions: when a user interacts with a view (e.g. by clicking something on a Web page), a specific controller action corresponding to that user activity is invoked.
>
>      - Each controller corresponds to one model, and in Rails, each controller action is handled by a particular Ruby method within that controller.
>      - The controller can ask the model to retrieve or modify information; depending on the results of doing this, the controller decides what view will be presented next to the user, and supplies that view with any necessary information.
> - **Schema**—a collection of all tables and their structure

The quiz question:

> Suppose RottenPotatoes.com wants to launch m.rottenpotatoes.com, an alternate version of the site for mobile clients. If the site was built using an MVC architecture, the majority of the work will go into writing new
>
> 1. views
> 2. models
> 3. controllers
> 4. schema

RottenPotatoes is a movie database that stores movies and their ratings. If a user searches for a movie and that movie is not in the RottenPotatoes database, then that movie will be added to the database.

According to my notes, "MVC advocates thin views & controllers". So I eliminated **(1) views** and **(3) controllers**.

That left me with **(2) models** and **(4) schema**. Based on their definitions, I selected **(2) models** as my answer because it seemed to contain the most information.

My answer was incorrect, so I'm wondering what mistake I've made and which answer would be more suitable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this site wants to be moved to a mobile version, then none of the actual data or functionality changes. Only the way the website looks will change.

- Models and Schema: these have to do with the raw data, and manipulation of that. So this won't change.
- Controllers: these are the functionality of the website, i.e. what happens if you push this button. This also doesn't change.
- Views: Views are how the data is represented to the user, i.e. how this data is displayed or where this button is positioned. This **will** change in a mobile version.

The correct answer should be Views.

Answer (score 2):

You're right about the premise of MVC advocating thin views and controllers, but you've drawn the wrong conclusion from it.

The correct answer would be **views**. The idea behind this is that only the front-most markup should be different between a desktop website and a mobile website; the logic that drives the views (the controllers) and the data used in them (the models and schema) should be identical no matter what sort of device should be used to access the site.

In a perfectly-architected MVC app, the *only* element that would change between the desktop and mobile versions would be the views. Of course, in the real world, there's usually a little more tweaking that has to go on to support a different scenario or context.

Answer (score 1):

> According to my notes, "MVC advocates thin views & controllers". So I eliminated (1) views and (3) controllers.

That's bullsh*t.

MVC advocates separation of concerns. And views in **real** MVC (not that joke that Rails pretends to be "mvc") are responsible for UI logic. They produce a response by assembling it from multiple template and applying [presentation objects](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) to said templates.

Views are not dumb templates.

Adding another interface for user to access is clearly a task that falls under "UI logic".

Answer (score 0):

**Views** is the only thing that might require changes and even that is questionable if you can make a good responsive design.